# bootstrap flash doesn't work with rails 4.1.4 and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having difficulties getting flashes to work with bootstrap_flash helper.
Here's a snippet of my code:

application.html.erb

```
...
<div class="container">
  <%= bootstrap_flash  %>
  <%= yield %> 
</div>
...
```

bootstrap_flash_helper.rb

```
ALERT_TYPES = [:error, :info, :success, :warning] unless const_defined?(:ALERT_TYPES)

def bootstrap_flash
  flash_messages = []
  flash.each do |type, message|
    # Skip empty messages, e.g. for devise messages set to nothing in a locale file.
    next if message.blank?

    type = type.to_sym
    type = :success if type.to_s == :notice.to_s
    type = :error   if type.to_s == :alert.to_s
    next unless ALERT_TYPES.include?(type)

    Array(message).each do |msg|
      text = content_tag(:div, content_tag(:button, raw("&times;"), :class => "close", "data-dismiss" => "alert") + msg.html_safe, :class => "alert fade in alert-#{type}")
      flash_messages << text if msg
    end
  end
    flash_messages.join("\n").html_safe
end
end
```

and I'm calling flash[:notice] in my controller actions.

Can somebody give me a hint on this one?
Thanks!

Comment: it crashes around here: def bootstrap_flash
    flash_messages = []
    flash.each do |type, message|
      
      next if message.blank?
raise

Comment: What is the exact error messsage? I think the last `end` is one too many...

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance the last `end` in your code is one too many.

On a second glance there are some flaws in your code in my opinion:

**(1) Avoid casting back and forth:**

```
type = type.to_sym
type = :success if type.to_s == :notice.to_s
type = :error   if type.to_s == :alert.to_s
```

You're casting `type` to a symbol, only to cast it back to a string while casting a constant symbol to a string to compare them. If you omit the `to_s` calls you can achieve the same thing without having to cast:

```
type = type.to_sym
type = :success if type == :notice
type = :error   if type == :alert
```

**(2) Use `map` instead of a helper variable + `each`:**

```
flash_messages = []
flash.each do |type, message|
  # ...
end
flash_messages.join("\n")
```

Instead of creating a temporary variable to turn the hash into an array, you can use `Enumerable`'s [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) or [`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) method to create a new array:

```
flash.map do |type, message|
  # ...
end.join("\n")
```

**(3) Use a mappings hash to map to CSS classes:**

```
ALERT_TYPES = {
 :alert => :error, :info => :info, :notice => :success, :warning => :warning
}
```

By using a hash like this you can simply do a lookup for the match, instead of having several `if` statements to determine the correct class

```
content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{ALERT_TYPES[type.to_sym]}")
```

Overall, this would be a far more readable, shorter and expandable solution, I think:

```
ALERT_TYPES = { :alert => :error, :info => :info, :notice => :success, :warning => :warning } unless const_defined?(:ALERT_TYPES)

def bootstrap_flash
  flash.map do |type, message|
    # Skip empty messages, e.g. for devise messages set to nothing in a locale file.
    # This will leave a nil value in the resulting array
    next if message.blank?

    # Skip if it's not a valid alert type
    # This will leave a nil value in the resulting array
    type = type.to_sym
    next unless ALERT_TYPES.keys.include?(type)

    # return the markup for the alert
    content_tag(:div, class: "alert alert-#{ALERT_TYPES[type]} fade in") do
      # use safe_concat() to avoid using html_safe()
      content_tag(:button, raw("&times;"), class: "close", data: { dismiss: "alert" }).safe_concat(message)
    end
  end.join('') # no need to join with \n --> this way nil values will be ignored as well
end
```